# If the contrapositive of a statement can be proven directly, can that statement itself necessarily be proven directly?

Tags: logic

So to be more formal: Given statements $A$ and $B$ such that a direct proof exists for $\neg B \implies \neg A$, is there necessarily a direct proof for $A \implies B$. By "direct proof," I mean a proof that does not ever assume $\neg B$.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Could you define "direct proof"?

Comment: This is probably theory-depedent.

Comment: @miniBill By direct proof, I mean a proof that doesn't use contradiction, nor the contrapositive.

Answer (score 3):

You say "I mean a proof that doesn't use contradiction, nor the contrapositive." So does that mean modus tollens is allowed in a direct proof? And conditional proof? And the double negation rules?

If so we can argue

> $$\neg B \to \neg A\\
> \quad | \quad \ \ \ A\\
> \quad | \quad \neg\neg A\\
> \quad | \quad \neg\neg B\\
> \quad | \quad \ \ \ B\\
> A \to B$$

And so we can convert a direct proof of the first into a direct proof of the second ....

If you think that's a cheat, you are going to have to say a LOT more about what you mean by a "direct proof".

Comment: Isn't $\neg \neg B\to B$ what one means by 'contradiction'?

Comment: @GitGud No it isn't.

Comment: how did you get from $\neg\neg A$ to $\neg\neg B$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Modus Tollens

Comment: By "direct proof," I meant a proof that does not ever assume $\neg B$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then my proof extension never assumes $\neg B$ so is direct.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about intuitionism, then the answer is no.

First, see that the other way works fine: $(a\implies b)\vdash (\neg b\implies \neg a)$:

Premise: $a\implies b$.

Assume $\neg b$.

Assume $a$.

By modus ponens and the premise, $b$.

Since $\neg b$, this is a contradiction.

Thus $\neg a$.

By implication, $\neg b \implies \neg a$. QED.

Now see what goes wrong the other way:

Premise: $\neg b \implies \neg a$.

Assume $a$.

Trying the same thing as before, assume $\neg b$.

Following the same reasoning, we get to … $a\implies \neg\neg b$, which isn't intuitionistically the same.

In fact, we can go further:

Accept the principle that $\neg b \implies \neg a\vdash a\implies b$.

Take my word for it that $\neg (a\lor \neg a)\implies \bot \implies \neg \top$ holds intuitionistically, where $\top$ is, say, $\neg(a\land \neg a)$.

Then applying the "risky" contraposition principle, $\top \implies a \lor \neg a$, so by modus ponens, $a\lor \neg a$.

That is, from the "reverse" contraposition principle, we derive excluded middle.

Answer (score 1):

If [($\lnot$A$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B)$\rightarrow$(B$\rightarrow$A)] comes as either an axiom or a theorem of your system, then if you have a proof of (¬B$\rightarrow$¬A), you can write a direct proof of (B$\rightarrow$A) by using the rule of detachment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the question:

> So to be more formal: Given statements A and B such that a direct proof exists for ¬B⟹¬A, is there necessarily a direct proof for A⟹B. By "direct proof," I mean a proof that does not ever assume ¬B.

We are given the following premises: $A$, $B$ and $\neg B \to \neg A$. The goal is to prove $A \to B$.  Here would be a proof using a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

The three premises are listed on on the first three lines. On line 4 I assume $A$. On line 5, I use reiteration to derive (reiterate) the second premise. On line 6 I use conditional introduction to derive the goal.

All one needs is the truth of $B$.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: By "given statements $A$ and $B$ such that there exists a direct proof for $\neg B\to\neg A$", the OP did not indicate that $A, B$ were *premises*.  Just that *if* $\vdash \neg B\to\neg A$ is proven, *then* can we also prove $\vdash A\to B$ directly (ie without using LEM or indirect proofs).